# Retrieve data using foreign key SQL

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, inner-join

I am new to sql database and i have problem retrieving data using the foreign key

I have two tables,

1- Task list

```
task_number(PK)  task_name    members
1                UIRE         Ahmed
2                DES          Omar
```

2- task_history

```
task_number(FK)  history   Date
1                Started   07-03
1                Feedback  07-03
1                End       08-03
```

I have program associated with, which the user chooses the task_name from combo box and then he should see the history of the task

For example, using the mentioned above table the user shall choose "UIRE" from a choose list the program shall run a script to retrive the history data of the task "UIRE"

which is:

```
history   Date
Started   07-03
Feedback  07-03
End       08-03
```

I have tried inner join, and the normal select statement. But I didn't found a solution.

Any idea of solving this? Is it possible to retrieve data using foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. An inner join will do the search you want.

For example:

```
select
  h.*
from task_list l
join task_history h on h.task_number = l.task_number
where l.task_name = 'UIRE' -- here's your filtering condition
order by h.date -- this line is optional. Use it you want the ordering by date
```